# TextBox control limits lines to 1024 characters regardless of WordWrap setting. How to increase?

Tags: winforms, textbox, word-wrap

The TextBox control (in a .NET winforms application) seems to hard limit line lengths to 1024 characters, even with the `WordWrap` property set to false. Is there a way override this?

I need to view lengthy data in a visual sense. Currently a line of 2000 characters wraps onto the second line and causes the right edge of several lines to be jagged rather than aligning.

Comment: Have you tried a RichTextBox?

Comment: A RichTextBox works, actually. Thanks. :) Though I still wonder if a TextBox can be extended, in case there's some overhead in using a RichTextBox that is unforeseen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Windows `Edit` control that the `TextBox` uses for its implementation has a limit of 1024 characters per line. This lmit has been around forever. Rather than fix it (which could cause problems with programs that somehow rely on this limit), they simply introduced the `RichEdit` control that doesn't have that limit and has many more features.

Comment: This also has a limit of 21414 characters per line.
I found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc4fe581-d7d1-45c4-8d9d-4fe5ad0ffd7f/richtextbox-max-line-lenght?forum=winforms

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541619/net-long-line-in-richtextbox-wrapped-after-3-510-characters