# .NET - Long Line in RichTextBox Wrapped after 3,510 Characters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a RichTextBox in a WInForms program that is wrapping any line that is longer than 3,510 characters.  I have WordWrap set to false, so all lines under that length extend normally without wrapping.  What I used to do to get around this was to set RightMargin to a high number such as 100,000, which still works, but now that I am on Windows 7 and not XP, I get a scroll bar that scrolls as though the text box had lines of that large length, when it doesn't.

To replicate, just create a winforms program with a RichTextBox and Button.  In the button's click event, put the following:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3511; i++)
            sb.Append('A');
        richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

After you see the wrapping, change the RightMargin of the text box to 100000, and notice the scrollbar that appears even before running the program (only on 7 and probably Vista).  The line no longer wraps, but I want the scrollbar to only act on the text in the box, and not some pre-determined length.

Comment: Is there not a better way to skin this cat then forcing the user to scroll so much to view the data?

Comment: I repro.  Looks intentional, *very* expensive to fix.

Comment: @Hans Yeah I did as well as it appears based on Font size...you can get more/less then 3510 depending on the Font properties, versus it being a hard value.

Comment: @Aaron My program is a text file viewer, so it needs to be able to display whatever the file has, exactly as it has it.  There are some rare delimited or fixed-width files we get that have lines longer than that, and I need to be sure that they are displayed correctly.

Comment: Understand you want to provide a carbon copy; however there are cues and ways to still provide the carbon copy but notifying the user that the line continues at point X and move it to another line, etc... Make the UI friendly for the user; just because the line of text is N chars long does not mean the UI has to display them in a single continuous line that forces the user to scroll indefinitely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set the rightmargin of the richTextBox to the width of the string? Like this

```
richTextBox1.RightMargin = 
TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), this.richTextBox1.Font).Width;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping for more of just a setting, but I can loop through each line in the text box, find the longest, and just set to that.

Comment: That's the maximum value it accepts: 143165576

Comment: Putting 0 will give the same results. It still wraps for very long lines.