# Turn off word-wrap in rich textbox in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, word-wrap

I am trying to read in the content of a file that has very wide records (6000+ characters) into a rich textbox. Although I have turned off wordwrap records still show wrapped after displaying a few thousand characters on a line. Anyway I can prevent wrapping until carriage-return/line-feed is encountered?

Answer (score 2):

<s>richTextBox.WordWrap = false;</s>

does this do what you want?

In think this question handles your problem:

[.NET - Long Line in RichTextBox Wrapped after 3,510 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541619/net-long-line-in-richtextbox-wrapped-after-3-510-characters)

Comment: Even with that the text gets wrapped automatically after a few thousand of characters. Even notepad behaves the same so I think this is a deliberate design.

Comment: @coolmine, you're right, and the topicstarter also mentions setting wordwrap to false.

Comment: Does the solution in the link you posted works for you ? I'm having a weird issue that after a number of characters (probably the point where it usually wraps the line) the characters don't get drawn properly and just appear transparent.